# C# Update UI In Task

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I am new to `C#` `Task` and threading.

I have a code like below:-

```
public void UpdateSales(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
    // Some code Create Collection ...
    // Some code with business logic  ..


    // Below code is to update UI
    // is it safe to update UI like below 

       saleDataGrid.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action) (() =>
                                {

                                    saleDataGrid.ItemsSource = currentCollection;
                                    saleDataGrid.Items.Refresh();
                                })); 

    });
}
```

I am not sure if this code is correct or not. I am think in any case deadlock can occur?

Can you please point how can i update UI from Task? i am not using `async/await`  because `UpdateSales` is event handler from third party library.

Comment: Usually you just call the Dispatcher and check if you need to invoke on it's specific thread. But I'm pretty sure your code won't cause a deadlock

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming that `UpdateSales` is called on the UI thread, a cleaner solution would be this:

```
public async void UpdateSales()
{
  var collection = await Task.Run(() =>
  {
    // Some code Create Collection ...
    // Some code with business logic  ..
    return currentCollection;
  });
  saleDataGrid.ItemsSource = collection;
  saleDataGrid.Items.Refresh();
}
```

As I describe on my blog, the [`await` will automatically resume on a captured context](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) (in this case, the UI context). I much prefer using the implicit context of `await` rather than `Dispatcher` directly: the code is shorter and more portable.

Comment: `UpdateSales` event is getting fire from COM object event handler. Not sure if that will be UI thread. I have edited this method signature in question to get it correctly.

Answer (score 12):

As you know, [Task.Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run(v=vs.110).aspx) will execute on a threadpool thread.

You can then use a [ContinueWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith(v=vs.110).aspx) which will run at the completion of that task - and if you choose [one of the overrides](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321307(v=vs.110).aspx) that allows you to specify a TaskScheduler then you can use [TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.fromcurrentsynchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) which will use the synchronization context that you entered the method on - if that is a UI thread (for example you are in an event handler for a UI event) then the synchronization context will be that of the UI thread.

So your code will look something like this:

```
Task.Run(() => {
    //...code to create collection etc...
}).ContinueWith(() => {
    saleDataGrid.ItemsSource = currentCollection;
}).TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```